# Use of t_family distribution in glmmTMB

Tags: r, distributions, glmmtmb

I am trying to use `t_family(link="log")` distribution from the glmmTMB package. The package allows fixing the shape parameter using `start = list(psi = log(fixed_df)), map = list(psi = factor(NA))`. In practice when I try to fix or not to fix, I get a very different result. My question is that what will be the effect of fitting a model with and without fixing the shape parameter, and which approach is correct? The AIC and deviance indicate a model with no fixed shape looks to fit better? The following is the code and the results :

```
glmmTMB(cypk~H*FL, family=t_family(link="log"), data= data,,start = list(psi = log(12)), map = list(psi = factor(NA)))
```

[image]
[image]

```
glmmTMB(cypk~H*FL, family=t_family(link="log"), data= data)
```

[image: Result from non fixed]
[image]